# How to constantly update a list of fixed length in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Sorry for the noob question. I'm just starting to code and I need to keep track of the 1hr price history.

I wanted pull values every second into a list of size 3600 until the list is filled, then shift the list to the left every second from there on out so the prices would stay constant.

```js
while True:
  polo = exchange.returnTicker()
  ethBtcRatio = polo["BTC_ETH"]['last']
  priceHistory = []
  ## What do I do here? Append?
  time.sleep(1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're using some terminology I don't understand.  Are you just trying to add on to the end of the list?  Are you trying to add on to the end of the list and remove the first item of the list if it's over 3600?  Both of these are easily searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append each new entry, then check the length of the list and conditionally `priceHistory.pop(0)`.

Looks like you're initializing the `priceHistory` list in the loop though. You want to do that before the loop, so you don't end up assigning empty lists to `priceHistory` every time.

Alternatively, and this depends on the use case, is that you can create an initial list with 3600 `None` entries, then just append and pop every time without the conditional length check.